# Describe the complex numbers that satisfy these sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Let $\alpha_i$ represent a sequence of complex numbers, where $i$ varies between $0$ and $N$. What's special about these numbers if they satisfy
$$\sum_{i=0}^N|\alpha_i|^2=1\;\;\text{ and }\;\;\left|\sum_{i=0}^N\alpha_i \right|^2=0?$$
I can't for the life of me see what relation these two equations imply. The only thing I've managed to extract from this is the fact that
$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^N\alpha_i \right|^2=0\iff\left|\sum_{i=0}^N\alpha_i\right|=0\iff\sum_{i=0}^N\alpha_i=0\iff\text{Re}\left[\sum_{i=0}^N\alpha_i\right]=0\land\text{Im}\left[\sum_{i=0}^N\alpha_i\right]=0$$
and that $\forall\alpha_i(|\alpha_i|<1)$ but even then I don't know what this really tells me about these numbers.

I'm looking for a succinct way to describe them; for example, if instead of those sums I was given $\forall\alpha_i(\alpha_i^2\in\mathbb{R})$ I'd know that every number in the sequence is its own conjugate, and therefore this describes a set of $N$ real numbers. I hope there's a methodical way to approach this, because I have another two sums that I have to describe, and I'm even more clueless about those.

Comment: Do you mean complex numbers that fulfill **both** sums at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried considering the situation with $N=1$, then $N=2$, etc.?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes

Comment: @MatthewConroy It did occur to me, but I felt like the small numbers obscured the pattern. Like for $N=1$ you just get $\alpha=0$, a trivial solution, If you take $N=2$ you get $\alpha_0=\alpha_1^*$, but after that there aren't any more trivial solutions (that I can see) and I still have the same issue seeing the pattern.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Actually, I totally take that back, looking at specific $N$ values was instrumental in finally solving this, but only after messing with the form of the equations a bit once I finessed them into sums of real numbers, it made it pretty easy to see that this defines $N$-sided figures. $N=1$ is a point, $N=2$ is a line, $N=3$  is a triangle, $N=4$ is a square etc.

Comment: @ocket8888 You're welcome. Cheers!

Comment: This has a few views, so I feel somewhat obligated to mention: I've solved the conundrum, and I'll post an answer in a few hours. I'm just a little too busy at the moment to write a proper one.

Comment: The tag ([tag:formal-proofs]) is for questions about proofs in various formal systems (e.g., natural deduction or Hilbert system), see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-proofs/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about rigorous mathematical proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the complex numbers $\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_{N-1}$ are *completely arbitrary* except for the property that they are not all zero. Define $$\beta_N = -\beta_1 - \cdots - \beta_{N-1}$$ and $$B = \sum_{i=0}^N |\beta_i|^2.$$

The numbers $\alpha_i = \dfrac{\beta_i}{\sqrt B}$ satisfy the two conditions. If these numbers are special they can't be too special since it is trivial to find examples.

Comment: the alternating sign from that sequence seems to me that it might imply some kind of trigonometric description. Just a passing thought.